# Normalize Vector3.Distance based on rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to measure distance between multiple positions but I do not want the rotation to affect the distance.  In concept, I want to track the starting transform and upon each update track the distance traveled without regard to the change in rotation.  I am using an HTC Vive controller and people tend to rotate their hands and I want to control for this.

I've tried resetting the Eular Angles, but this doesn't seem to work.

### Adding an Analogy that will certainly help.

Think of it like trying to draw and measure a line with a pencil, the position is in the eraser, and I can hold the pencil in any number of ways and in fact change the position in the middle of drawing the line, but my line will remain straight and the measurement will remain accurate.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish? `transform.position` and `transform.rotation` don't affect each other, so I think we are missing a piece.

Comment: Yeah, it's not immediately clear what kind of issue you're facing. The only possibility I can currently think of is if a transform was rotated around a point, but we'll need more details before we can help.

Comment: Sorry, that was a poor question. Think of it like trying to draw and measure a line with a pencil, the position is in the eraser, and I can hold the pencil in any number of ways and in fact change the position in the middle of drawing the line, but my line will remain straight and the measurement will remain accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem lies around the position you are tracking. It sounds like you are tracking the `transform.position` of one of the child elements of the Vive controller model, leading to the situation that you're describing with the pencil eraser analogy.

Depending on where your script is attached, you could either move this to the top level element of the Vive controller, or alter your script to instead track `transform.parent.position`, which shouldn't be affected by the rotations of someone's hand.